# How to call on isSameTree function?

Tags: c++

I'm writing code to see if two trees are the same. I'm confused on how I call on my function isSameTree function from the Driver.cpp file. I have included my isSameTree function which is located in a file called BinaryTree.cpp and Driver.cpp file.

```
    // Driver.cpp
    int main() {
    
        // Binary Trees that are the same
        BinaryTree treeOne;
        BinaryTree treeTwo;
        
    
        treeOne.insert('abc');
        treeOne.insert('def');
        treeOne.insert('ghi');
    
    
        treeTwo.insert('def');
        treeTwo.insert('abc');
        treeTwo.insert('ghi');
    
        
    
    
    
        // Binary Trees that are differnt
        BinaryTree treeThree;
        BinaryTree treeFour;
    
    
        treeThree.insert('abc');
        treeThree.insert('def');
    
        treeFour.insert('abc');
        treeFour.insert('ghi');
        treeFour.insert('def');
    
        std::cout << "Tree three and four are NOT the same." << std::endl;
    
    }
    
// Located in BinaryTree.cpp
    bool BinaryTree::isSameTree(BinaryTree* anotherTree)
    {
        
        std::vector<int> t1, t2;
    
        toVector(&t1);
        toVector(&t2, anotherTree->root);
    
       
        if (t1 == t2) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Similar to how you call `insert`, but instead of passing a string, you pass the tree you want to compare to.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly about what you are asking, then you simply need to call as below

```
treeOne.isSameTree(&treeTwo);   
//OR equivalently 
treeTwo.isSameTree(&treeOne);
```

Both the statements should return true, if everything is fine.

Similarly, for the third and fourth trees.